# AX 2009 Document Management File Handlers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

**Background**

Dynamics AX 2009 allows you to attach files to various records, e.g. associating a word document with a customer record.
The file types you can choose are defined under `Basic` > `Setup` > `Document Management` > `Parameters` > `File Types`.

We've recently had a request to make the Outlook Mail Message format (`*.msg`) available.  We work in a terminal server (Windows 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Services) environment, so to allow users to open such files we'd need to install appropriate software onto the terminal servers.  I'd prefer to avoid this overhead, instead allowing users to download the file to their local machine, opening it there.

**Question**

Is there a way to make attached documents downloadable over TS in some way (perhaps offering a save dialogue where a user can specify a UNC location, if they can't simply have such documents opened in a client app over TS).

One thought I had was to develop a custom program which only saves files; associating this with all file types not supported by existing handlers.  However I'm hoping there's a simpler, existing solution out there already.

Comment: You'd probably be better served to use remoteapp instead of TS if you're essentially trying to ignore the remote desktop.

Comment: @JimB; apologies, we're using RemoteApp with icons presented over RDWeb; my use of TS is just me using outdated terminology.

Comment: NB: Also asked here: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/193907

Comment: Have you tried using the remoteapp RDP file on the clients directly? You should be able to set the redirect to the local drive

Comment: Hey @JimB, not sure I understand.  To clarify, say I have a .TXT file on the RDS server which I want to open with Notepad on my laptop.  Using a remote app hosted on the server I click a button which causes the server OS to attempt to open the file; how do I set it up to know to use Notepad on my local machine?  Does your answer solve that issue / can you point me to an article describing the steps involved?

Comment: ps. potential solution; using DVCs: https://rdpaddins.codeplex.com/ - i.e. this coule transfer the file over the RDP connection, then the clientside code could `invoke-item` to open the transferred file.